# Intermittent "An item with the same key has already been added" error during remote MSDeploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msdeploy

While invoking MSDeploy to deploy a webpackage to a remote computer, we're getting the following error:

```
msdeploy.exe -source:package='G:\workspace\webPackage\WebPackage.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="HOST",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"G:\workspace\webPackage\SetParameters.xml" 
Error: (12/10/2015 2:55:36 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.SanitizePath(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest.GetTraceMessage(String[] additionalMessage)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.BeginProcessRequest(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
```

This looks to be happening somewhere in the depths of MSDeploy. The weird thing is that it doesn't happen consistently; running this command again seems to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any duplicate items in your package?

https://forums.iis.net/t/1149928.aspx?An+item+with+the+same+key+has+already+been+added+

[Upon one-click publish: Exception in executing publishing: An item with the same key has already been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298598/upon-one-click-publish-exception-in-executing-publishing-an-item-with-the-same)

Comment: I can double check, but we are deploying this package to multiple machines and this only happens on one at a time (and not always the same one).

Comment: Does anything change when you deploy from one machine to another? Maybe some config files?

Comment: Nope, we're doing sequential invocations of MSDeploy. Interestingly enough, it only seems to happen on the first invocation.