# Unable to perform database compare

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

Recently, not since three or four days, we have been facing an issue when trying to compare within visual studio 2013 on a database project. The compare screen loads up but I'm not able to select source or target. Nothing happens if I click the target combo and select "Select target...". Sa for source. I tried using the menu bar's "SQL" with the compare screen open and tries "Select Target" from there only to be presented with a error message: An item with the same key has already been added. Same behaviour on source.

We tried reading the logs of visual studio, searched all over internet and got suggestion to update SSDT but thats not really an option as the search results are from 2011/2012 and those update don't exists or apply to VS2013.

We did more testing:

- A stand-alone new solution with new DB projects works fine
- Loading our DB project directly into a new solution works fine
- Our full solution 'A' fails.
- Other of our solutions 'B' and 'C' also fails
- Couldn't find anything in the solution file that could prevent comparing.

Anyone facing/had similar issues?

Comment: That rings a bell about something with caching that someone else had and solved by clearing out some cache or other (vague, but that's what comes to mind). I know it's not completely relevant, but have you tried installing the SSDT 2012 IDE/bits to see if it works on your machine with those? Tried another machine with VS 2013? Haven't had the issue myself, but found similar references like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003914/vs2010-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added

Comment: Everyone (7 machines) with VS2013 and the default latest SSDT is experiencing same thing. Works fine outside the solution.

Comment: I was able to use the Schema Compare function in VS 2013 by right-clicking the project and selecting Schema Compare. I was then able to select source/target servers with no issues. This might be something specific to your solution. I still think it's worth trying the standalone SSDT bits for the VS2012 IDE to see if that works. You may also want to hit up the MSDN SQL Server forums about this. There are MS people on those who could likely analyze your project for issues.

Comment: @PeterSchott, Thats exactly how we used to do it a few days ago. can't really find anything in the solution that might be preventing/breaking the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS2010. Solved after renaming projects with the same name which were located in different virtual solution folders. 
Looks like "New Schema Comparison" form doesn't respect solution folders structure when fills "Project" combobox.